# Boot Repair thinks it’s not in a live environment (19.10)

Tags: 19.10, boot-repair, live-environment

I added the universe and multiverse repos required to install boot-repair on a 19.10 live environment, but when I run it, it thinks it’s on a real Ubuntu installation rather than a live environment. Why is this, and can I fix it?

Comment: Just a guess, but I have a bootable .iso of boot-repair, it probably is differentiating between that live environment and being installed somewhere else.

Comment: Some others have had similar issue. I found this bug. Probably best to add your info and say it also effects you. https://bugs.launchpad.net/boot-repair/+bug/1853705